# Switch from Wayland to Xorg gives black screen

Tags: xorg

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1 and I'd like to switch to Xorg. When i edit the file in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and disable Wayland, the screen goes black and i have to re-enable it from recovery mode.

I have xserver-xorg installed and i have the right Intel driver (i915).

here's the log:
https://pastebin.com/L2QxXsqM

I tried to google it but i didn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps go the terminal/command prompt and run sudo apt-get install gnome. When  you click the password entry box at login there a  circle should appear in the right bottom corner you can select either Wayland or Xorg Gnome or Ubuntu. Check what you are running with

```
loginctl
loginctl show-session <SESSION_ID> -p Type
```

or

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

Comment: I installed Gnome and tried to log in with GNOME on Xorg, GNOME Classic on Xorg and again on Ubuntu on Xorg but all of them just show a black screen still. GNOME and GNOME Classic work fine though.